# creating a relative path in .vbs file

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a pdf file, generated by Latex, which contains hyperlinks to open an excel file (excel 2003).
I posted a question to Latex forums
in 
[enter link description here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283318/link-to-a-specific-worksheet-in-an-excel-file)
 so that I can make each link opens the excel file on a specific cell; but no one could give me the answer. 
I found an answer by   brettdj
in   [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854263/what-the-win-cmd-to-open-a-particular-spreadsheet-in-excel)

which uses a vbs file to open a specif cell in the excel file.
The problem is that the file location (in strFileName =) is an absolute, so when I take the vbs and excel file to another folder

or to another computer, the link does not work; and a message "file not found" is displayed.

**Is there a way to do this, or to make the path to the excel file relative to where the vbs file is located; so that when the vbs**

and excel files are moved to another location the file can still be opened.

I posted this question in
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34460028/editing-vbs-to-accept-a-parameter)
but I got no answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim objFSO
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim CurrentDirectory
CurrentDirectory = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(".")
```

I saved the VBS as `C:\Users\Jonno\Documents\test.vbs` - It gives the output `C:\Users\Jonno\Documents`. To use it put something like

```
strFileName = CurrentDirectory & "\test.xlsx"
```